# Android EditText and Button on same line

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-button

I need to have a `Edittext` beside a `Search button`. The `EditText` should fill as much of the width as possible, the button should be to the right and be just big enough to have it's text.

It looks like this now:

```
[EDIT TEXT][Search]
```

but should look like this:

```
[.......EDIT TEXT.......][Search]
```

Here is the `XML`:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="type to filter"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_box"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Here is answered https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172714/button-encima-de-un-edittext/173975#173975

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Does it have to be Relative Layout?
I would suggest the following: set `EditText` `layout_width` to `fill_parent` and its `layout_weight` to 1, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" 
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</EditText>
<Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest using LinearLayout instead of Relative, as well. I think then you need to specify the layout_width not as wrap_content or fill_parent, but 0dp or some other minimum acceptable width.

Answer (score 10):

In that case, the width for the `EditText` must be set to `fill_parent` (instead of `wrap_content`):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="type to filter"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_box"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

#### Edit

As you said, it hides the button. Then, just invert the order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="type to filter"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe Cristian's answer works on later versions of the SDK, but for prior versions what you'll need to do is define the Button first, and place the EditText to layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_box", which, by the way, both objects should have different IDs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="type to filter"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this i have fixed little. it shows button right of edit text and also edit text width allowed to increase.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="instructions"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignRight="@id/entry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:text="ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a solution for a *Relative Layout*, try this. My goals was to keep the button size the same but adjust the EditText field when the phone was rotated to landscape mode or on different phone screen sizes.

So the trick is to use a combination of margins and aligning the parent to the start. Here is something you can try, I pulled this directly from my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemEntry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/itemEntry"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What you'll get is the EditText will change in size depending on screen-width while the button will remain fixed at the end. The button sticks at the end because of `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`. And to stop the EditText from overrunning the Button, `android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"` is used. Hope this helps!

Comment: What difference from other posts?

Comment: It uses a RelativeLayout and it I offered a bit more explanation as to how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The better answer now is set layout_width of EditText to 0dp

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<EditText
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"/>
 <Button
    android:text="Button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```